# Certain context menus are slower to open

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

This has been the case for every version of Windows that I've used, from Windows 95 through to Windows 8 Release Preview. And Not just on my computer, on other's too - I'm sure you've noticed this.

When you right click on a file, the Desktop or on a Folder, why does the "New" sub-menu take longer to display, than any other system-based menu?

I understand that it may have something to do with determining which Icons to display based on what listings should appear in the "New" menu, but still - there are other sub-menus that have the same functionality, yet appear instantaneously.

[image]

Comment: Have you an example of " other sub-menus that have the same functionality, yet appear instantaneously."

Comment: I always set all instances of **MenuShowDelay** in the registry to **0** and there's no delay anywhere that I can notice! :)

Comment: Yes, I have only just reformatted by PC so I won't be uploading new pics since I haven't reinstalled everything yet, *but* a good example would be TortoiseSVN or TortoiseHG or whatever it's called; that has like a gazillion items in the menu!

Comment: @Karan: I was thinking there might be a delay setting, though I couldn't find it when I looked. I'll look again, thank you.

Comment: Note that a delay of 0 might be too fast for some people, but I prefer it. You can also disable/remove all unwanted items from the New menu using something like [ShellMenuNew](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_new.html).

Comment: @Karan: I found the **MenuShowDelay** in the Registry and set it to 0, but didn't notice any difference. So I then set it to 10, 000. Still no difference. Am I missing something here :-$

Comment: Did you change all the instances? Did you then logoff/logon, restart Explorer or better still, reboot after making the change? Menu display should speed up several notches.

Comment: Yeah I restarted.

Comment: The main **MenuShowDelay** setting is under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. There are a couple of instances under HKEY_USERS as well, which I guess will vary from machine to machine. If changing all these made absolutely *no* difference at all, that's really weird. What happens if you right-click inside a folder? Don't the *View, Sort by, Group by, Share with* and *New* sub-menus open up *much* faster now (almost instantaneously) than before?

Answer (score 1):

Those "other sub-menus" do not have the same functionality at all. Those other menus are all statically designed whereas the New sub-menu is dynamically generated.

What this means is that Tortoise SVN has predetermined what options should be on that menu well ahead of time and primed Windows with all the images and text and functions that need to be called from those menu options.

The New menu on the other hand has to [scan the registry](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-remove-items-from-new-menu-in-windows/) to find out what items need to have an option in the New menu, it has to go to the disk to find icons for those items and it needs to work out what to do when someone clicks on those items. The problem is that it has to do this each time you look at that menu because if you install a program then you might well expect new items to appear in that list at any random time.

Basically those menus are not the same and they are working on two different sets of assumptions. One is static and rarely changes, the other is dynamic and can change any time a program wants it to. Disk caching can make the New menu fast-ish, but that doesn't make up for the fact it needs to do work before it shows you the list.